# How to setup Varnish logging?

Tags: logging, varnish

I want to get Varnish to log requests. I found the command `varnishlog -a -w /var/log/varnish.log`, but it does not log anything.

Then I found that Varnish does not write to log by default. However I am unable to find configuration options for logging.

Comment: Note also when using varnishlog -w with version < 3.0.3, you have to restart it after every varnish restart.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you want to log HTTP requests in [NCSA Common Log Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Log_Format) you need to use `varnishncsa`. On CentOS/RedHat, the Varnish RPM package includes a varnishncsa init script that you can use to start logging. By default it logs to `logfile="/var/log/varnish/varnishncsa.log"`.

Additionally if you wish to serve several different hosts through a single Varnish install, you'll want to include the host name in the log as well. This can be accomplished with the following setting in `/etc/sysconfig/varnishncsa`

```
DAEMON_OPTS="$DAEMON_OPTS -F '%{Host}i %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-agent}i\"'"
```

Please note that the method described in the link by Anshu only logs the requests that are passed through by Varnish to the backend servers. *Cache hit requests will never be recorded* (before Varnish 5.0 - see below). Therefore the HTTPD logs gathered this way cannot be used for statistical analysis.

**Update:** As @VikrantPogula mentioned, as of Varnish 5.0 all client requests are logged - including cache hits. This is the default behavior, and can be switched on explicitly using the `-c` switch.

Comment: To actually enable the logging on Ubuntu:

edit `/etc/default/varnishncsa`

uncomment `# VARNISHNCSA_ENABLED=1`

run `sudo service varnishncsa restart`

Comment: I was not able to use the -F option in `/etc/default/varnishncsa` (Ubuntu 14.04), probably because of the shell handling quotes in strange ways. When I tried to restart the service via `sudo service varnishncsa restart`, the usage options for varnish were displayed but the service wasn't started. Looks like an unresolved bug to me, see: http://giantdorks.org/alain/workaround-for-broken-varnishncsa-logging-due-to-shell-mishandling-of-spaces-in-log_format-variables/ and https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=657449

Answer (score 6):

Metrics in Varnish are a common area that people struggle with.

It's relatively easy to get some one off request metrics but overall tracking over time generally involves using varnishncsa. Here is a [guide on Varnish installation](http://www.section.io/varnish-install-quick-and-detailed/) that includes metric setup

Answer (score 3):

In response to Ketola's answer, you can have varnishncsa log even Cache hit requests, by passing the `-c` flag. This will allow you to use HTTPD logs to analyse stats.

Example : `varnishncsa -c -a -w ~/varnish.log` will write cache hit requests to the file in default NCSA format

Answer (score 3):

The files `/etc/default/varnish*` are deprecated in systems with systemd. just run these commands:

```
systemctl enable varnishncsa.service
systemctl start varnishncsa.service
```

you can also modify the daemon parameters in `/lib/systemd/system/varnishncsa.service`

Answer (score 1):

Since i landed here and the suggested fixed did not help:

My varnishncsa.log was empty and the process was running.

It turned out, that i HAD TO specify the log format (any format).

As this insight in itself did not fix my init script, i fixed it using [this strategy](https://lists.gt.net/varnish/misc/24863#24863).