# How can I override Magento product view logging

Tags: magento

My site uses varnish cache heavily and is set to refresh every 5 minutes. I found out that this was skewing product view stats making them less than what they actually should be.

1. I want to turn off Magentos default product view logging facility so that no product views are being recorded.
2. I want to mimic the action by doing custom inserts into the relevant tables i.e. `tf_report_viewed_product_index`

Inserting into the `tf_report_viewed_product_index` table alone is not allowed since it has foriegn key constraints. There is more to it.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone comes across this you can use xml to disable an event:

```
<frontend>
        <events>
            <catalog_controller_product_view>
                <observers>
                    <reports>
                        <type>disabled</type>
                    </reports>
                </observers>
            </catalog_controller_product_view>    
        </events>
    </frontend>
```

Then using an ajax call from the product view page I simply insert a new row into `tf_report_viewed_product_index` table.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a Magento issue, this is a user-request-reaching-your-web-app (Magento) issue. The speed and load-handling benefits realized by using Varnish exist precisely because pre-generated static content is cached and served ahead of the dynamically generated content from Magento (which also includes the overhead and resources of logging traffic to the `report_*` and `log_*` tables).

I've not too much experience in this area, but I believe you should use `varnishcsa` to log cache hits and then process them via cron using the Magento Report module's modeling; see [`Mage_Reports_Model_Event_Observer::catalogProductView()`](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Reports/Model/Event/Observer.php#L124) for a start, but note that this method normally handles logging of single views. You will likely want to do a mass insert of processed Varnish log data and then calculate.

And, [here's a link SO post on setting up logging with `varnishcsa`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12706903/833795).

Comment: Thanks benmarks this is a decent solution to the problem. I've started working on a solution which I will share below.