# How I can see in varnish which Agents (Browsers or bots agents ) request a certain url

Tags: varnish, varnish-4

I have 2 box
first frontend - with nginx + varnish
second backend - apache

How i can see for a certain URL Agents that request (hit) it in Varnish?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to setup Varnish logging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12705252/how-to-setup-varnish-logging)

Answer (score 1):

you want varnishncsa:

```
varnishncsa -q 'ReqURL eq "/whatever/url/you/want"' -F "%{User-agent}i"
```

this will give you real-time output, it you just want to see whatever you have in the backlog, add `-d`:

```
varnishncsa -q 'ReqURL eq "/whatever/url/you/want"' -F "%{User-agent}i" -d
```

In doubt, `man varnishncsa`, it has all the info about the format string, and you can look at `man vsl` and `man vsl-query` for mor info about the `-q` argument.